# Ethereum full nodes Bandwidth usage

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node

I have a query about data transfer(bandwidth) average/approx cost per month ethereum node incurrs after it's been hosted for a year.

what could be inbound and outbound data usage?

Comment: There are various network monitoring tools available that can help you track data usage, such as iftop, vnstat, or other similar tools.